# Search from multiple nested level fields in elasticsearch

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I want to search from multiple nested level fields. query like.

```
select * from product where brand='brand1' and category='category1'.
```

In elasticsearch I have **two nested level mapping** one is **category** and other is **brand**.

If i wrote **only brand** or category it **return perfect result** but **how to write both in following query ?**

```
    $params = [
                'index' => 'my_index',
                'type' => 'product',
                'body' =>  [
                "query"=>[
                   "filtered"=>[
                      "filter"=>[
                         "bool"=>[
                            "must"=>[
                               "bool"=>[
                                  "must"=>[
                                     [
                                        "query"=>[
                                           "match"=>[
                                              "brand"=>[
                                                 "query"=>"brand1",
                                                 "type"=>"phrase"
                                              ]
                                           ]
                                        ]
                                     ],
                                     [
                                        "query"=>[
                                           "match"=>[
                                              "category"=>[
                                                 "query"=>"category1",
                                                 "type"=>"phrase"
                                              ]
                                           ]
                                        ]
                                     ]
                                  ]
                               ]
                            ]
                         ]
                      ]
                   ]
                ]
            ]      

       ];
```

**By above query I am getting 0 result**

Comment: I dont have an idea how to write that query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query it will help you out to get respected answer:

GET /product/ur_type/_search
    {
     "from": 0,
     "size": 200,
     "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "query": {
                                        "match": {
                                            "brand": {
                                                "query": "brand1",
                                                "type": "phrase"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "query": {
                                        "match": {
                                            "category": {
                                                "query": "category1",
                                                "type": "phrase"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
     }

Comment: please tell me what exactly it giving you as ouput??

Comment: BadRequest400Exception in GuzzleConnection.php line 277: and the looonngg error like : {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures.............

Comment: can you please share your query with me?